# What does "od" stand for in linux and why is it useful?

Tags: linux, text, terminal

I'm curious about what "od" in linux does and what it means. I'm running it on a text file test.txt that contains the phrase:

```
I am pretty
```

It then returns these numbers:

```
0000000 020111 066541 070040 062562 072164 000171 0000013
```

Is this useful and what can I use it for?

Comment: `man od` - "od - dump files in octal and other formats"

Comment: It is useful when you are looking for not-so-pretty characters.

Comment: Nowadays, I think `xxd` is to be preferred, IMHO.

Comment: Probably not.  It is not standardized, and was added as an afterthought to support vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has grown somewhat (see [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=od&sektion=1) and [GNU](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) for instance),  but originally (see [1st](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/od) and [6th](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/od) editions of Unix), `"od"` was an abbreviation for **o**ctal **d**ump.

You would find the original (1st edition) not useful.  But since the 6th, **od** has been generally useful with

```
od -bc filename
```

For example

```
0000000   056 124 110 040 117 104 040 061 040 012 056 123 110 040 116 101
           .   T   H       O   D       1      \n   .   S   H       N   A
0000020   115 105 012 157 144 040 134 055 040 157 143 164 141 154 040 144
           M   E  \n   o   d       \   -       o   c   t   a   l       d
0000040   165 155 160 012 056 123 110 040 123 131 116 117 120 123 111 123
           u   m   p  \n   .   S   H       S   Y   N   O   P   S   I   S
0000060   012 056 102 040 157 144 012 133 012 056 102 040 134 055 141 142
          \n   .   B       o   d  \n   [  \n   .   B       \   -   a   b
0000100   143 144 157 170 012 135 040 133 040 146 151 154 145 040 135 040
           c   d   o   x  \n   ]       [       f   i   l   e       ]
0000120   133 040 133 012 056 102 040 053 012 135 157 146 146 163 145 164
           [       [  \n   .   B       +  \n   ]   o   f   f   s   e   t
0000140   133 012 056 102 122 040 042 056 040 042 040 042 135 133 042 012
```

which is fairly readable, though not quite like the actual file (quoting from 3BSD):

```
.TH OD 1
.SH NAME
od \- octal dump
.SH SYNOPSIS
.B od
[
.B \-abcdox
] [ file ] [ [
.B +
]offset[
.BR ". " "]["
```

The original dumped only in *octal*, largely due to the influence of the PDP-11: with 8 registers, encoded in 3 bits, that meant a lot of instructions were best read in octal.  The default in later versions was octal of course for compatibility.

Comment: The question specifically asked when is od useful. Some example of practical applications using od would have been better. I also would like to know when I actually need it and probably many others who have reached this post.